# Multiple login pages

Tags: web2py

My problem is this.
I have a few urls from which you can actually login.
Problem is that if I hit login and its invalid it takes me to a different page which apperently is nowhere defined.

to describe situation, I have login page under /order/login... and if anything is wrong it keeps redirecting me to /default/login - I have no idea why?

Another problem is I do want to define a default login page for when someone wants to access a url restricted.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is very simple:

> auth.settings.controller = 'order'

and it can be defined as inline in controller or in db.py.

Also it can go to init of Auth

> Auth(db, controller="order")

Answer (score 2):

`auth.settings.login_url` is the URL of the login page, which by default is set to /default/user/login. If your login URL is /order/login, then assuming "order" is the controller and "login" is the function, just do:

```
auth.settings.login_url = URL('order', 'login')
```

If someone then tries to access a URL that requires login, they will be redirected to that URL.

Comment: Problem is, I know how to set default. But I have other pages and apparently as I explained above if I enter any of them errors return to the default login page and not to the page from which login origianted.

Comment: You can set auth.settings.login_url conditionally depending on the current controller and function. You can also specify the Auth controller and function when you initialize Auth -- `auth = Auth(db, controller='order', function='login')`. Can you provide more detail regarding what is happening. If you go to /order/login, what kind of error happens, and where do you get redirected after that error?

Answer (score 0):

Use HTTP-REFERRER to get the URL the user is from and redirect to it. I don't know how to do this in Web2py but I hope this points you in the right direction.

Goodluck

Comment: There are other concers. I understand http-referrer ;]